# Re-use externalised tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external

I have a small diagram, drawn using TikZ, I would like to use in more than one place in a document.
Given that I activated the TikZ externalisation features (I need them for other purposes than this diagram alone), is there a way I can use the PDF of the first diagram when I want to include it again in the text, instead of just copying the code for the diagram, that would result in unnecessary duplication and more compilation time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `\includegraphics`. The `external` library creates PDFs for each diagram, which are named either sequentially or by what you define via `\tikzsetnextfilename`. So if you have `\tikzsetnextfilename{foo}` that creates `foo.pdf`, and you can later do `\includegraphics{foo}`.

Complete example, modified from one found in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{trees}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

Then reuse the tree:

\includegraphics{trees}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there advantages to doing the above, vs. making standalone tikz document just to generate the image pdf, and then use `\includegraphics{}` to load these images? I mean, I would probably have a separate folder, where all the tikz images are created, each using its own latex file. Then include these images in the main latex documents from any where.

Comment: @Nasser Whatever floats your boat, I suppose. If you consider having everything in one place an advantage, that's one for the `external` library. Also, you don't have to take any care to get matching font setups for example.