# Re-using externalised tikzpicture always fails for no discernible reason

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, shell-escape

This MWE works, based on the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493209/re-use-externalised-tikzpicture). However, attempting to achieve the same result in a real document always fails to generate the external image, usually with an error along the lines of: `! error:  (file cache/image-name.pdf) (pdf inclusion): reading image failed`.

The `\includegraphicsmaybe` command ought to skip over the unavailable image on the first pass, but something is trying to read the image before it is ready. Is it possible to modify the command so it never gets run during the TikZ external routine? Removing the file extension from that command results in the image never being included, but the document compiles correctly.

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true }
% arara: tikzmake: { options: ['-j1'] }
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=cache/,shell escape=-enable-write18]
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --halt-on-error --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
\tikzset{
  % Defines a custom style which generates BOTH, .pdf and .png export
  % but prefers the .png on inclusion.
  %
  % This style is not pre-defined, you may need to copy-paste and
  % adjust it.
  png export/.style={%
    external/system call/.add=%
      {}
      ; convert -density 300 -transparent white -transparent-color white "\image.pdf" "\image.png",
  },
  png images/.style={%
    external/system call/.add=%
      {}
      ; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png",
    % Don't need this as we're keeping the PDF in the document
      /pgf/images/external info,
      /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
        \includegraphics
        [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
        {##1.png}%
      },
  }
}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\tikzset{png export}
\tikzexternalize
\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[1]{\IfFileExists{#1}{\includegraphics{#1}}{File #1 is missing.}}
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{trees}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

Then reuse the tree:

\includegraphicsmaybe{cache/trees.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The TikZ external run fails when the image is reused elsewhere in the document because `\IfFileExists` will return true—it only checks that the file exists, not whether it is valid. Even though `lualatex` shouldn't be running any code elsewhere in the document at this point, it does, so we need a way to prevent the incomplete image file from being loaded.

The solution is to amend the externalizing routine so that it outputs a file when the job has completed, then make `\includegraphicsmaybe` search for that file before attempting to input the image.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=cache/,shell escape=-enable-write18]
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --halt-on-error --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
\tikzset{
  % Defines a custom style which generates BOTH, .pdf and .png export
  % but prefers the .png on inclusion.
  %
  % This style is not pre-defined, you may need to copy-paste and
  % adjust it.
  png export/.style={%
    external/system call/.add=%
      {}
      ; convert -density 300 -transparent white -transparent-color white "\image.pdf" "\image.png",
  },
  png images/.style={%
    external/system call/.add=%
      {}
      ; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png",
      % Don't need this as we're keeping the PDF in the document
      /pgf/images/external info,
      /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
        \includegraphics
        [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
        {##1.png}%
      },
  }
}
% Checks that images are OK
\tikzset{
  external/system call/.add={cat "\image.ok" && rm "\image.ok"; }{ && date > "\image.ok"},
}
% Skip files that haven't been rendered yet
\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[1]{\IfFileExists{#1.ok}{\includegraphics{#1}}{File #1 is missing.}}
```

The `cat "\image.ok" && rm "\image.ok"` call removes the status file before compiling, preventing any `\includegraphicsmaybe`s that depend on that file from running during the TikZ make stage. I thought it was useful to output the date into the status file, but YMMV.